# Gimp smooth edges coloring

Tags: gimp, png, blending

I have a PNG image with transparency. It is an icon of single color and I want to change its color.

What I have done so far is,

1. Select the area I want, either by Fuzzy select or the color select tool.
2. Color with the bucket fill.

However I get rough edges, not blended with the transparent background.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem that is the following,

1. Select what you want NOT faded. Use any selection tool you want.
2. Next go to Select > Invert
3. Now go to Select > Feather - feather by 3
4. Select Edit > Clear

In case the image is already anti-aliased,

1. Right click on the Layer from the Layers Dock
2. Select Alpha to Selection
3. Bucket Fill

Comment: Works great, would be nice if there was more explanations on what each step is doing though… That would help me fine tune the final result.

Comment: I've had to repeat that operation like 3 times with Feather 10 to get the result I wanted. So maybe you will need to play some more with the Feather to see if you can get it done in one path.